# Trying to get content of span in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'C:\\Users\\Zandrio\\Documents\\Python-Selexion\\HTML-localhost\\Selexion.html'

page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="lxml")
prettify = soup.prettify
Model = "".join([div.text for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title-options'})])
print(Model)
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Zandrio> & C:/Users/Zandrio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Requests/selexion.py

                                        SQQE55Q90R

                    Merk:
                    Samsung                  Afdrukken
```

HTML:

```
<div class="title-options">
<span>
 SQQE55Q90R
</span>
<span>
  Merk: Samsung                
</span>
<span class="print"> <a href="/nl/pr/samsung-qled-qe55q90r/product-sheet" class="product-file-pdf" target="_blank" title="Afdrukken">Afdrukken</a>
</span>
</div>
```

I just want the Model number in this case, that is SQQE55Q90R here. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: `model_no = soup.select_one('.title-options span:first-of-type').text`

Comment: PS C:\Users\Zandrio> & C:/Users/Zandrio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Requests/selexion.py

                                        SQQE55Q90R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'C:\\Users\\Zandrio\\Documents\\Python-Selexion\\HTML-localhost\\Selexion.html'

page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="lxml")
div = soup.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'title-options'})
model_number = div.span.text.strip()  # text of first span

print(model_number)
```